# Prevent special characters in string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have this regular expression and I need to prevent a password having any of these symbols: `!@#$%^&*()_`, it is working for `!@#$%` but not for this password `!@#$%D`.

```
$scope.matchPatternPassword = new RegExp("[^!@#$%^&*()_]$");
```

Comment: I read it 5 times and can't understand what you're asking. Can you post more code, or try to phrase it better (It that's google translator, it's getting worse)

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande here test website a0197766.xsph.ru with right form if push on button my cabinet in password if write !@#$% all it work but so !@#$%D not it work

Comment: Ok I believe I got it, password must not contain any of these characters: [^!@#$%^&*()_]$  but  `!@#$%D` is working when it shouldn't:
In other words: `!@#$%D` **BAD**, yes?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande if in string have any from  forbidden symbols this means error and user need delete forbidden symbol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168477/discussion-between-vadim-and-marcos-casagrande).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex was only checking for any of those symbols at the end of the string, that's why the one ending in a letter was working.

The regex should be:

```
$scope.matchPatternPassword = /^[^!@#$%^&*()_]+$/;
```

This matches any string that doesn't have any of those characters.

Here's a working example: https://regexr.com/3nh9f

```js
const regex = /^[^!@#$%^&*()_]+$/;

const passwords = [
 '!@#$%',
 '!@#$%D',
 'yes',
 'valid-password',
 'im-valid-too',
 'invalid$',
 'super!-invalid',
 'mypassword'
];

console.log(passwords.filter(password => regex.test(password)));
```

Comment: Why did you use the non-greedy quantifier `+?`?

Comment: To be honest, because regexr was bothering me matching the new line. (Go to my regexr link), and forgot to remove it when posting the answer here, since his regex isn't multiline.